# How can I check for all exceptions using try & except without pep8 warnings in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, error-handling, try-except

I'm trying to check for all possible errors using `try` and `except`, but when I use `except Exception as e:`, pep8 says "too broad exception clause". I tried adding `logging.exception(e)` but now it doesn't work at all (I remembered to import logging).

Comment: PEP-8 is only a style guide for python. Your code will work fine with a broad `except`, it just warns you that you should specify the exception whenever possible.

Answer (score 0):

PEP8 is all about to follow standards and write code that is easy to read, find bugs easily and many more things. PEP 8 is saying that warning because you are not mentioning any `Exception` type. Though this is harmless but not a good practice at all. You should be more specific whenever you handle exceptions as this may help you to narrow down your bugs.

Example

```
def foo():
    try:
        1/0
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print("You can not divide by zero")
    except Exception as e:
        print("Some unknown error occurred. Error is: " + e.__str__())

def bar():
    try:
        raise Exception("I am crashed")
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print("You can not divide by zero")
    except Exception as e:
        print("Some unknown error occurred. Error is: " + e.__str__())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo()
    bar()
```

You get the idea. Never write except without any Exception type.